# Using Now() vs Date() in MS-Access Table Definition

Tags: ms-access-2007

It is probably customary to use Date() as the default value in the table definition default value and constraints. However, I was wondering what would be wrong if I use Now() instead?
When I use Now() i get the time in addition to the data, which is something I want. Is there a problem with this? 
[image]
Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you need the timepart, that's what to do.

Comment: Thank you for your help.